# drupal update select list based on another select list

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal, so here is my question:

I need to create content type Students, inside this content type there should be the following fields:

Name
Age
Gender
Course

The gender field is select list from Male or Female, if the user select Male, that should load the courses of males only in the "Course" select list, and if the user select Female, that should load the courses of females only in the "Course" Select list.

How can I do this?? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For which version of Drupal you need this? Edit question please.

Maybe you can use: https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

Or you can find example with ajax callback for dependent dropdown. It was in Example module for D7.

Answer (score 0):

Found it thank to @blastoise.
you can achieve this using client side hierarchy select module https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs

Thanks.